# Ember JS Browser "Back" Button & Redirect Conflict

Tags: browser, ember.js

Im using the following `afterModel` hook inside an `Ember.Route`:

```
afterModel: function() {
  this.transitionTo("order", 1);
}
```

So when we visit `#/orders`, it redirects to `#/orders/1`

It works just fine, however once i get to #/orders/1, if I click the browsers back button, I get taken to #/orders and the `afterModel` hook doesn't fire again to cause another redirect.

Is there any way to completely prevent #/orders from displaying and force the redirect trigger to always fire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ember.Route.replaceWith seems to do what you need. Take a look at:
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_replaceWith

Answer (score 0):

if you want to always redirect from #/orders use redirect hook rather afterModel. it goes like this

```
redirect: function() {
  this.transitionTo("order", 1);
}
```